# Jquery target span after current element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to find the next instance of an element at the same level.

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<some html />
<span></span>

<div id="foo2"></div>
<span></span>
```

What jQuery selector would allow me to target the next span for foo and then foo2. I took a look into next, siblings and closest, but I couldn't get anything to work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll) together with the [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector):

```
$('#foo').nextAll('span:first')
```

Alternatively, use the [next siblings selector `~`](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector) (known in CSS3 as the general sibling selector) together with the `:first` selector:

```
$('#foo2 ~ span:first')
```

[Preview both on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/j3fyT/2)

Comment: Nice answer and good links too. I actually saw the next siblings selector documentation, but got confused because the title has 'prev ~ siblings.' I had read that as 'previous siblings' which was not what I was looking for.